# Как сделать скролл сравнения товаров как у Эльдорадо?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Есть ли готовое решение чтобы сделать скролл сравнения товаров как на сайте эльдорадо? Вот пример [ссылка](http://www.eldorado.ru/cat/compare.php?section=17374&ids=385888116d155341219d155341495d33385472d285833364d172638680&dir=0&sku=71168845,71094147,71094148,71086869,71124148,71101420).

Тоесть, есть блока с картинкой товаров, под ним скролл который прокручивает и блок с картинками и блок с характеристиками, при пролистывании страницы блок закрепляется сверху. Может кто знает как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Ни каким скролами не заманишь в эльдородо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почти уверен, что можно нашаманить только через css, но проще сделать так:

```js
var scrollSource = document.getElementById("si");
var scrollDest = document.getElementById("sd");

scrollSource.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  scrollDest.scrollLeft = scrollSource.scrollLeft;
})
```

```css
#si { overflow: auto; }
#sd { overflow: hidden; }
/* Внимание! Надо обеспечить одинаковую ширину их контента! */
```

```html
<section id=si>
   12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
</section>
<section id=sd>
  <div>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
  <div>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
  <div>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
  <div>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
  <div>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Ну как то так:

```js
$(function() {
  var elem = '.header',
      to_elem = '.contant',
      epos = $(elem).offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= epos){
      $(elem).css({position: 'fixed', top: 0});
    }else{
      $(elem).css({position: 'initial'});
    };
  });
  $(elem).scroll(function() {
    $(to_elem).scrollLeft($(elem).scrollLeft())
  });
});
```

```css
.main {height: 4000px; padding-top: 50px;}
.header {width:250px; height: 100px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden}
.header .list {width: 660px;}
.header .list .item {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color:red; margin: 0 5px; float: left}
.contant {width:250px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;}
.contant .list {width: 660px;}
.contant .list .item {width: 100px; height: 500px; background-color:red; margin: 0 5px; float: left}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contant">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: там еще влево/вправо можно двигать скролл на фиксированном блоке, а прокручиваться будет основная таблица :)

Comment: Спасибо. Но тут вопрос в другом, как реализовать скроллинг двух объектов одним скролом, по ссылке можно увидеть что это два независимых блока, а скролл у них один

Comment: Изменил ответ. Смотрите

Comment: Спасибо большое, как раз то что нужно!